# Save Personal Files From Win 7 Partition Before Installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows

***Intro***

I was gifted a Toshiba Lifebook T2010 Tablet/Laptop that had Windows 7 Ultimate installed.  I have dabbled with Linux, off-and-on, for many years but I am only familiar with the OS, but not proficient compared to most.  I am comfortable with command line as it seems to be better in most ways when installing applications or fixing "work-around" issues.

I decided that I want to use it to try Linux again as I recently found a copy of Scrivener for Linux to continue my writing.  I also plan to dual-boot with Remix OS to take advantage of the tablet feature with an Android OS to get the best of both worlds.

***Issue***

I have personal files on the non-boot, Windows 7 partition that I want to keep but cannot backup at this time as I only have a 1 GB thumb-drive that I use for Hiren's Boot CD.

That said, is there any way that I can use GParted or Mini XP on Hirens to possibly shrink the volume without losing said data so that I can initially install Ubuntu?  If I can then it should be possible to move the data from the old Windows 7 partition to Ubuntu and then completely absorb the Windows 7 partition completely after the data move correct?

Thank you for any assistance that you can provide!

Comment: You should have a backup before you start resizing partitions. Flash drives are not that pricey these days.

Comment: You can use gparted but we suggest buy some larger USB sticks for creating recovery media for Windows as well as backing up important data.

Comment: You should have a backup in any case. Anything can happen (this device drops, you spill some water-or soda-or alcool-or coffee on it, there is a jump in the electric tension and it burns out) and your data is gone in the blink of an eye.

Comment: gparted does not do backups and resizing partitions can (rarely) cause data loss, so backup first if you value your data.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I decided to use my daughter's computer and I will place the laptop HDD in the external case I thought I lost and copy the data to her computer.  I will then install Ubuntu.  Thank you very much for the help and advice!